# Add parent element to child element to have one tuple (when converting XML to dictionary collection)

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, elementtree, xml.etree

my ad-hoc question relates to the following

given this xml structure (saved in xml_FILE):

```
<countriesAndStates>
  <countries>
    <name>USA</name>
    <states>
      <active>true</active>
      <stateName>Colorado</stateName>
      <isoCode>CO</isoCode>
    </states>
    <states>
      <active>false</active>
      <stateName>Florida</stateName>
      <isoCode>FL</isoCode>
    </states>
  </countries>
</countriesAndStates>
```

I traverse the state element level via this for-loop and save the result to a dictionary of lists through the help of collections from defaultdict as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
tree = ET.parse(xml_FILE)
root = tree.getroot()
    
dict_of_list = defaultdict(list)
for key in root.findall("./countriesAndStates/"
                              "countries/"
                              "states/"):
    dict_of_list[key.tag].append(key.text)
```

I then transform this dict to a dataframe and I'll have all the tuples containing the state element's data, cf.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_of_list)
print(df)
```

This way I get the following dataframe output (scheme + tuple):

```
     active    stateName isoCode               
0    true      Colorado  CO
```

However, I want to have the country for each state tuple
such that each tuple/row in dataframe will transform to:

```
    name  active    stateName isoCode               
0   USA   true      Colorado  CO
```

In other words: for each state/record I want the country name too.
How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Upload **VALID** xml doc and show the required output.

Comment: @balderman here you, I tried my best

Comment: can you add another state to the example?

Comment: @balderman sure, there you go and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd


xml = '''<countriesAndStates>
  <countries>
    <name>USA</name>
    <states>
      <active>true</active>
      <stateName>Colorado</stateName>
      <isoCode>CO</isoCode>
    </states>
    <states>
      <active>false</active>
      <stateName>Florida</stateName>
      <isoCode>FL</isoCode>
    </states>
  </countries>
</countriesAndStates>'''

data = []
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for country in root.findall('.//countries'):
  name = country.find('name').text
  for state in country.findall('states'):
    data.append({'name':name})
    for e in list(state):
      data[-1][e.tag] = e.text
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
  name active stateName isoCode
0  USA   true  Colorado      CO
1  USA  false   Florida      FL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
That does the job :)

Comment: **1)** `root.findall('.//countries')` => `root.findall('countries')` **2)** `for e in list(state)` => `for e in state`